# cakephp site is not converted into other language

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working into CakePHP framework.I have to create multilingual site.So I have created to language file.

Step-1 : created two file in app/locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po and app/locale/spa/LC_MESSAGES/default.po

Step-2 : I have written

```
msgid "ENGAGE YOUR FOLLOWERS."
msgstr "REALIZAR SUS SEGUIDORES ."
```

in **spanish default.po** file. When I hvae change language english to spanish than its not converted into spanish language.

So how can I resolved this problem?

**Note :-** I am working with CakePHP version 1.3.13

Comment: `When I hvae change language` - how are you doing that? The translation doesn't make sense btw, and [that version is archaic](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/1.3.11) - are you starting a new project with that version?

Comment: no I have assign this project in lower version

Comment: I don't know what that means but you haven't answered my (main) question.